# Usage of template parameters subtype (advanced case)

Tags: c++, templates, circular-dependency, compile-time

I have a few classes with following inheritance relations:

```
template <typename ID_t>
class Identifiable {
public:
    virtual ID_t unique_ID() const {
        return 0;
    }
};
template <typename DerivedName>
class SomeBase : public Identifiable<typename DerivedName::ID_t> {
public:
    virtual DerivedName & instance() = 0;
};
template <uint16_t SomeParam = 5>
class SomeDerived : public SomeBase<SomeDerived<SomeParam>> {
public:
    using ID_t = uint16_t;
    SomeDerived & instance() override {
        return *this;
    }
    ID_t unique_ID() const override {
        return SomeParam;
    }
};
int main() {    
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    SomeDerived<> instance;
    std::cout << std::to_string(instance.unique_ID()) << std::endl;
}
```

But this doesn't compile with "No type named ID_t in class SomeDerived" in the line of `SomeBase` declaration. Even though the reason seams to be quite obvious, is there a way to force compilation without this check? Or fix it without passing `ID_t` as another template parameter?

Here is a link to a sandbox: [cpp.sh/57ox6](http://cpp.sh/57ox6)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a type alias from `Identifiable`:

```
template <typename ID>
class Identifiable {
public:
    using ID_t = ID;
    virtual ID_t unique_ID() const {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is the OP is trying to use `SomeDerived::ID_t` before it is defined.

Comment: @AshotVardanian: please post your original code then.

Comment: @RSahu exactly. I have spent an hour thinking of a complex solution... but for now just added another template param. Need some fresh ideas)

Comment: @erenon it has lots stuff not related to problem. I have just copied the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `SomeDerived::ID_t` before it is defined.

You can refactor the classes a little bit to make it work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename ID>
class Identifiable
{
   public:
      using ID_t = ID;
      virtual ID_t unique_ID() const {
         return 0;
      }
};

template <typename DerivedName>
class SomeBase
{
   public:
      virtual DerivedName & instance() = 0;
};

template <uint16_t SomeParam = 5>
class SomeDerived : public Identifiable<uint16_t>,
                    public SomeBase<SomeDerived<SomeParam>>
{
   public:
      SomeDerived & instance() override {
         return *this;
      }
      ID_t unique_ID() const override {
         return SomeParam;
      }
};

int main()
{    
   std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
   SomeDerived<> instance1;
   std::cout << std::to_string(instance1.unique_ID()) << std::endl;

   SomeDerived<20> instance2;
   std::cout << std::to_string(instance2.unique_ID()) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
5
20
```

Comment: Yes, thats pretty obvious. But it doesn't fit my needs. I wanted to find a workaround to force compiler to do deeper type deduction. Thanks for participation!

Answer (score 0):

> Even though the reason seams to be quite obvious, is there a way to force compilation without this check? Or fix it without passing ID_t as another template parameter?

It is not a problem of *forcing compilation without this check*. What you are trying to do violates the rules of the language, that's all. Therefore it's malformed code that cannot be compiled.
In other terms, within `SomeBase` you are trying to use a type (`SomeDerived`) that isn't fully defined. Therefore you cannot expect `DerivedName::ID_t` to be there. And you cannot expect to be able to tell to your compiler - *ehy, dude, ignore the C++ standard and compile this, whatever it is*.

@R.Sahu posted a valid workaround with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210533/4987285), maybe the shortest and most effective solution you can get.
Another option is to use traits as in the following example:

```
#include<cstdint>
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Identifiable {
    using ID_t = T;

    virtual ID_t unique_ID() const {
        return 0;
    }
};

template<typename>
struct SomeTraits;

template <typename DerivedName>
struct SomeBase : public Identifiable<typename SomeTraits<DerivedName>::ID_t> {
    virtual DerivedName & instance() = 0;
};

template <uint16_t SomeParam = 5>
struct SomeDerived;

template<uint16_t SomeParam>
struct SomeTraits<SomeDerived<SomeParam>> {
    using ID_t = uint16_t;
};

template <uint16_t SomeParam>
struct SomeDerived : public SomeBase<SomeDerived<SomeParam>> {
    using ID_t = typename SomeBase<SomeDerived<SomeParam>>::ID_t;

    SomeDerived & instance() override {
        return *this;
    }

    ID_t unique_ID() const override {
        return SomeParam;
    }
};

int main() {    
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    SomeDerived<> instance;
    std::cout << std::to_string(instance.unique_ID()) << std::endl;
}
```